# Get f1 score for a specific class with cross-validation

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I have a binary classification problem that has a low `f1 score` for the second class.

I need both `f1 scores` to be good since I am trying to predict the probability of an item getting sold. 
My dataset is also unbalanced if that helps.

I think my model is generalizing instead of making the correct predictions.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `metrics.classification_report()`

```
Eg) print metrics.classification_report(y_test, y_pred)


            precision    recall    f1-score   support

        0       0.11      0.21      0.14        24
        1       0.18      0.21      0.20        42
        2       0.14      0.15      0.15        39
        3       0.12      0.12      0.12        48
        4       0.19      0.13      0.16        52
        5       0.20      0.04      0.07        23

avg / total     0.16      0.15      0.15       228
```

Answer (score 0):

### 1) Here is a full example using `iris` dataset with `train-test spliting`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import svm, datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report

# import data
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target
class_names = iris.target_names

#keep only 2 classes to make the problem binary
X = X[y!=2]
y = y[y!=2]

# Split the data into a training set and a test set
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=0)

# Fit the classifier using the training data
classifier = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=0.01)
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Predict using the trained classifier and the test data
y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)

print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred, target_names=class_names))

             precision    recall  f1-score   support

setosa            1.00      1.00      1.00        13
versicolor        1.00      1.00      1.00        12

avg / total       1.00      1.00      1.00        25
```

---

### 2) Here is a full example using `iris` dataset with `KFold cross-validation`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import svm, datasets
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_predict
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold

# import data
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target
class_names = iris.target_names

# keep only 2 classes to make the problem binary
X = X[y!=2]
y = y[y!=2]

# Define the classifier
classifier = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=0.01)

# KFold cross validation
cv = KFold(n_splits=3)

y_pred = cross_val_predict(classifier, X, y, cv = cv)

print(classification_report(y, y_pred, target_names=class_names))

            precision    recall  f1-score   support

setosa           0.98      1.00      0.99        50
versicolor       1.00      0.98      0.99        50

avg / total      0.99      0.99      0.99       100
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answering my question. I'm actually using the DecisionTreeClassifier for this since I noticed that trees are more effective at discriminating my data than other types. By that I mean it at least has an f1-score greater than zero for the negative class. I was thinking more of plugging in the just the f1-score for the negative class into the scoring parameter of GridSearchCV. I wanna do this so that I can determine what parameters to use for the Decision Tree before boosting it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the party, but for anyone finding this from the ✨future✨, try this:

```py
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score

y_true = [1, 0, 1, 0, 0]
y_pred = [1, 1, 1, 0, 1]

f1_score(y_true, y_pred, average='binary')
```

It will return the score for the positive class (`True`/`1`). You can confirm this by printing out the classification report as described above.